# How to change state due to action on a different composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'd like to appologise first, I'm trying to follow the MRE guidline, but, since it's my first time doing it, I might not ommiited enough code to make it as simple as possible, I will try to get better at this s I progress.

I am having a bit of trouble to work how to recompose animation upon action.

I have two data classes just for the sake of keeping things orginaize as mucha s I can:

```
class DataSize(val width: Float = 0f, val height: Float = 0f, val expand: Float = 0f) {}
data class DataCoordinates(val x: Float = 0f, val y: Float = 0f) {}
```

I also have a composable that represents a playing card, which, receives information about the location where it needs to snap on (because that snappable area can and should be dynamic to be changed)
Once the object is being released out of that snapable area, it returns to it's original position:

```
@Composable
fun CardBox(
    title: String,
    initCoordinated: DataCoordinates = DataCoordinates(),
    boxDimensions: DataSize = DataSize(),
    placementDimensions: DataSize = DataSize(),
    lockCoordinated: DataCoordinates = DataCoordinates(),
    z: Float = 0f,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val cardInitWidth = boxDimensions.width
    val cardInitHeight = boxDimensions.height
    val cardInitWidthInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { (cardInitWidth).dp.toPx() }
    val cardInitHeightInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { (cardInitHeight).dp.toPx() }
    val marginSpace = 150
    val lockCoordinatedMarginLow = DataCoordinates(x = lockCoordinated.x - marginSpace, y = lockCoordinated.y - marginSpace)
    val lockCoordinatedMarginHigh = DataCoordinates(x= lockCoordinated.x + marginSpace, y = lockCoordinated.y + marginSpace)
    val placementDimensionsWidthInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { (placementDimensions.width).dp.toPx() }
    val placementDimensionsHeightInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { (placementDimensions.height).dp.toPx() }
    val enabledDragging = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val clickable = Modifier.clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = LocalIndication.current) {}
    val size = animateSizeAsState(targetValue = if (enabledDragging.value && !isPressed) { Size(width = cardInitWidth, height = cardInitHeight) } else { Size(width = cardInitWidth + boxDimensions.expand, height = cardInitHeight + boxDimensions.expand) })
    val offsetX  =  remember { Animatable(initialValue = initCoordinated.x) }
    val offsetY  =  remember { Animatable(initialValue = initCoordinated.y) }
    val zV = remember { mutableStateOf(z) }
    val atLockPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zIndex(
                zIndex = if (enabledDragging.value && !isPressed) {
                    zV.value
                } else {
                    100f
                }
            )
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                    y = offsetY.value.roundToInt()
                )
            }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(size.value.width.dp, size.value.height.dp)
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black))
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            enabledDragging.value = !enabledDragging.value
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consumeAllChanges()
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                offsetX.snapTo(targetValue = offsetX.value + dragAmount.x)
                                offsetY.snapTo(targetValue = offsetY.value + dragAmount.y)
                            }
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessHigh, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            enabledDragging.value = !enabledDragging.value
                            if (offsetX.value in lockCoordinatedMarginLow.x..lockCoordinatedMarginHigh.x && offsetY.value in lockCoordinatedMarginLow.y..lockCoordinatedMarginHigh.y) {
                                atLockPosition.value = true
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    launch {
                                        offsetY.animateTo(
                                            targetValue = lockCoordinated.y + ((placementDimensionsHeightInPx - cardInitHeightInPx) / 2),
                                            animationSpec = tween(
                                                durationMillis = 500,
                                                delayMillis = 50,
                                                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                            )
                                        )
                                    }
                                    offsetX.animateTo(
                                        targetValue = lockCoordinated.x + ((placementDimensionsWidthInPx - cardInitWidthInPx) / 2),
                                        animationSpec = tween(
                                            durationMillis = 500,
                                            delayMillis = 50,
                                            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            } else {
                                atLockPosition.value = false
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    launch {
                                        offsetY.animateTo(
                                            targetValue = initCoordinated.y,
                                            animationSpec = tween(
                                                durationMillis = 700,
                                                delayMillis = 50,
                                                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                            )
                                        )
                                    }
                                    offsetX.animateTo(
                                        targetValue = initCoordinated.x,
                                        animationSpec = tween(
                                            durationMillis = 700,
                                            delayMillis = 50,
                                            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                            spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow, visibilityThreshold = 0.1.dp)
                        }
                    )
                }
                .then(clickable)
        )
    }
}
```

I have another composable to represent a hand of playing cards, this one is the tricky one because as far as I want to it behave, is, once you pull out a card out of the hand, it size should shrink automatically (and it doesn't do it currently, see the GIF I attached):

```
@Composable
fun CardHand(
    cardDimensions: DataSize = DataSize(),
    placementDimentions: DataSize = DataSize(),
    lockCoordinated: DataCoordinates = DataCoordinates(),
    numberOfCards: Int
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    val dmWidthInPx = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val cardDimensionsInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { (cardDimensions.width.dp.toPx()) }

    val singleCardOffset = 100
    val cardCounter by remember { mutableStateOf(numberOfCards) }

    repeat(cardCounter) {
        val dataCoordinates = DataCoordinates(x = (dmWidthInPx - ((cardDimensionsInPx) + ((cardCounter - 1) * singleCardOffset))) / 2 , y = 0f)
        CardBox(
            title = "Box_$cardCounter",
            initCoordinated = DataCoordinates(x = dataCoordinates.x + (it * singleCardOffset), y = 50f),
            boxDimensions = cardDimensions,
            placementDimensions = placementDimentions,
            lockCoordinated = lockCoordinated,
            z = cardCounter.toFloat(),
            content = {}
        )
    }
}
```

[image: current operation]

So basically, I see my issue as passing the state of the snapped card onto the hand composable so that I'll be able to recomposite how it looks, and that's where I struggle.

Comment: So the problem is that the card returns to the original position when you pull it back from the stack? Now you store all card position logic inside `CardBox`, if you wan't to control positioning from outside you need to make your `CardHand` a source of truth - it should know which cards are in the stack and which are not. The exact implementation is up to you.

Comment: Actually, that one I got... so the return position should be outside of that composable, which makes sense, yes.
What I am struggling with is the positionning of all the cards in that hand, but, come to think about it, if the pulling is outside of that composable, then the calculation of the position should also be outside.